# Vue - Make bootstrap tooltips reactive based on i18n language

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-5

I am using bootstrap 5 on a vue 3 project. My app uses vue-i18n for localization and language selection.

i18n.js:

```js
export const createI18nInstance = () => {
    return createI18n({
        legacy: false,
        locale: localStorage.getItem('app-lang') || navigator.language || 'en',
        messages: {
            en,
            'en-US': en,
            ja
        }
    })
}

export const i18n = createI18nInstance()
```

When I hover on a text (en), I expect to see a bootstrap tooltip having a translated text (jp).

I need this functionality to work two way, that is if the language selected is english, then I want the tooltip to show a japanese translation. And if I switch the selected language is japanese, I want the tooltip to be updated with the english translation.

However, the problem is at the first time I hover on a text (en), it works as I would expect which is showing a jp tooltip. Then after I switch languages (to jp), and hover on the same text component again, the tooltip still shows the jp translation.

It seems the problem is that the tooltip isn't being "updated" when the user switches locale. Here is the vue component:

```js
<script setup>
import { Tooltip } from 'bootstrap';
import { i18n } from '@/locales/i18n';

const lang = ref(i18n.global.locale.value)

onMounted(() => {
    new Tooltip(document.body, {
        selector: "[data-bs-toggle='tooltip']"
    })
})

onUpdated(
    lang,
    () => {
        new Tooltip(document.body, {
            selector: "[data-bs-toggle='tooltip']"
        })
    }
)

const tooltipText = computed(() => {
    if (i18n.global.locale.value === 'en') {
        return props.todo.content_jp
    } else {
        return props.todo.content_en
    }
    
const taskText = computed(() => {
    if (i18n.global.locale.value === 'en') {
        return props.todo.content_en
    } else {
        return props.todo.content_jp
    }
})
</script>

<template>
                <span data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-placement="right" :data-bs-title="tooltipText"
                    class="d-inline-block text-truncate" style="max-width: 100%;">
                    <span :class="{ 'strikethrough': props.todo.completed }">
                        {{ taskText }}
                    </span>
                </span>
</template>
```

Comment: It looks like you are creating a new tooltip each time so the old tooltip is probably in front of the new one. You should be destroying the old tooltip before creating a new one. This might fix your issue, but it will also resolve what I think is a memory leak. Also, `onUpatded()` doesn't seem to take two parms. I think you should be using `watch()` instead. https://vuejs.org/api/composition-api-lifecycle#onupdated